# Repeat numbers multiple times when generating multiple numbers

Tags: php, random

I am trying to generate some numbers but i don't want all of them to be unique.I want if i am generating numbers from `1` to `100` to repeat one number `n` times.

I have this snippet in mind to make the value of `i` variable to a number i want repeated,but it can get complicated if i want to repeat another number like `50` and so forth.

```
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
$rand_val =  rand(1,100);
if($i = 12)
$rand_val = 40;
}
```

Is there a random numbers generation class that allows me to generate duplicate and non-duplicate numbers?.

Comment: If the requirement is non-duplicate, it is no longer random.

Comment: I want a bunch of numbers generated,why is random = unique? Is statistically random taken to mean random? Oh never mind http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness i have found the meaning.

Comment: No, random is not unique, you could theoretically end up with a hunderd times the same number. If you put restraints on it (like uniqueness), it is no longer random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ensures `$special_value` occures *at least* `$num_special_occurance` times. It may occur more often if it is randomly drawn.

```
$num_numbers = 10;
$special_value = rand(1, 100);
$num_special_occurance = 5;
$numbers = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_numbers - $num_special_occurance; $i += 1) {
    $numbers[] = rand(1, 100);
}
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_special_occurance ; $i += 1) {
    array_splice($numbers, rand(0, count($numbers) - 1), 0, array($special_value));
}

var_dump($numbers);
```

Generate 5 (10-5) random numbers, then add the special value 5 times in a random place.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array.
This way you can generate random numbers and check if they have been already generated before adding them to the result.

```
$numbers = [];
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
   do { $rand_val =  rand(1,100); } while ( in_array($rand_val, $numbers) );
   $numbers []= $rand_val;    
}
print_r($numbers);
```

This will give you 10 **unique** random numbers in range 1-100.

**Note**: it will hang if the number of numbers you're looking for is wider than the range. Like, if you're trying to find 200 unique random numbers in 1-100 range. So keep that in mind.